# Can't launch War Thunder through Steam

Tags: steam, war-thunder

I am trying to play War Thunder through Steam on my ubuntu 14.04, but I can't launch it through Steam. When directly launching by clicking the 'launcher' file in the local folders works just fine. Any solutions for this? I signed into Steam while playing this awesome game. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with almost any problem in Steam, the first solution to try is to validate the game files.

Right-click War Thunder in your Steam Library, then select **Properties**.

In the **LOCAL FILES** tab, select **VERIFY INTEGRITY OF GAME CACHE**.

This will take a few minutes to run through and check your files.

If that doesn't work, another common problem with War Thunder is that antivirus software might be blocking the file *aces.exe* from launching. Make sure that file is in your antivirus whitelist!

Comment: I validated the game cache, Steam downloaded something, restarted but when I click "play", I got 'Failed to start game: app already running'. War Thunder haven't launched.

Comment: In that case, find the program aces.exe in your System Monitor and close it, then try again. It sounds like the game is running in the background, and that's why Steam can't launch it.